# Magento admin product edit page remove or change for quantity attribute

Tags: admin, magento2

Who know how can I remove or modify quantity attribute in admin product edit page!

I check the magento doc for product_form.xml forUI component, I have changed qty successfully in advance stock page, but for main page quantity I didn't find out where I can change it, some people can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Module\CatalogInventoryEdit\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Attributes extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    private ArrayManager $arrayManager;

    /**
     * Initialise dependencies.
     *
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager)
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * Included to appease AbstractModifier.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array $data
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data): array
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array $meta
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
    {

        return $this->customizeAttributes($meta);
    }

    /**
     * Modify meta customize attribute modal.
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    private function customizeAttributes(array $meta): array
    {
        $meta['product-details']
        ['children']['container_quantity_and_stock_status']
        ['children']['quantity_and_stock_status']
        ['arguments']['data']['config'] =
            [
                'componentType' => 'container',
                'label' => __('Stock Status'),
                'visible' => false,
            ];

        $attribute = ['quantity_and_stock_status_qty'];
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attribute, $meta, null, 'children');
        return $this->arrayManager->set(
            "$path/arguments/data/config/visible",
            $meta,
            false
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).